# Entry can only occur once for one M2M relation

Tags: python, django

I have Items and Recipes (which is linked to an Item it creates), where a Recipe uses a `through` Model to define the number of Items in the Recipe.

Now I have the following problem; I want to restrict the Recipe to only have an Item once, no matter the quantity.

So if I have item `Bread` and add `Flour` x1, `Butter` x2 `Sunseeds` x2. After that I want to raise an error if I someone tries to add one of those Items again.

How could I do that?

**Update**

`unique_together` would be a solution, on the `recipe_id` and `item_id`?

**Update 2 (some code)**

```
class Recipe_Has_Items(models.Model):

    recipe = models.ForeignKey('Recipe')
    item = models.ForeignKey('Item')
    quantity = models.IntegerField(validators = [MinValueValidator(0)])

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s (%d)' % (self.item, self.quantity)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Recipe\'s Item'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Recipe\'s Items'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand `Recipe` has a `ManyToManyField` to `Item` and in the through table you have defined three field `recipe` (`ForeignKey`), `item` (`ForeignKey`) and `item_count`. Now you want that, for a recipe an item can be used once at max (with item_count >= 1). So, yes, adding `unique_together` for `recipe` and `item` in through table would work.

Comment: So `unique_together = (('item_id', 'recipe_id'), )` would work? Does Django put the actual restrictions on my MySQL database too or does it just mimic it with the Model on entering the data? I would not like to destroy data by doing a faulty schema migration :P

Comment: It seems the Docs confirmed my question (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/options/#unique-together). Thanks for the confirmation Debanshu.